# C# configure RESTful routes

Tags: c#

I want to have a routes

`{domain}/v1/images/{id}` and `{domain}/v1/images/{email}`.

The first route is working (for example: `v1/images/1?size=100`) but when I try the second (for example: `v1/images/foo@domain.com?size=100` I get this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get(Int32,
>   System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' in '....ImageController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter."

I have my routes configured like this:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Image",
            routeTemplate: "v1/images/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Image", size = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ImageByEmail",
            routeTemplate: "v1/images/{email}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Image", size = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Is it possible to get the image by id or email?

Comment: You need a method inside your `ImageController` which accepts `string email` as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router has no chance to identify whether `v1/images/foo@domain.com?size=100` goes to `/v1/images/{id}` or `/v1/images/{email}`. It silently chooses `/v1/images/{id}` and tries to parse `"foo@domain.com"` as `int`, parsing fails and since `id` parameter `(int id)` is not optional (as opposed to `(int? id)`) it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Image",
        routeTemplate: "v1/images/{id}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Image", 
            size = RouteParameter.Optional, 
            id = @"\d+" }
    );
```

The `@"\d+"` will validate the id as a number.